# C# creating class for JSON

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to built a class using the following JSON format in C#.

```
{
  "incident": {
    "name": "string",
    "status": "investigating",
    "impact_override": "critical",
    "deliver_notifications": true,
  "body": "string",
    "components": {
      "47l0w2s8lp6s": "operational"
    },
    "component_ids": [
      "p15tdc1kwhg6"
    ] 
 }
}
```

I was able to create most of the class but having issues with components section of the JSON. How Do it make a string of numbers and letters into part of the class ? 47l0w2s8lp6s
Any suggestions of guidance is appreciated

```
 public class Components
    {
        public string 47l0w2s8lp6s { get; set; }
    }
public class Incident
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string impact_override { get; set; }
    public bool deliver_notifications { get; set; }
    public string body { get; set; }
    public Components components { get; set; }
    public IList<string> component_ids { get; set; }
}

public class incidentModel
{
    public Incident incident { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: use this website for json to csharp https://json2csharp.com/ paste in your json and you are good to go.

Comment: https://quicktype.io/csharp

Comment: `public Components components` should likely be `public Dictionary<string, string> components` But use one of the above two links to start with.

Comment: besides of using Dictionary, you can also decorate your property with `[JsonProperty("47l0w2s8lp6s")]`

Comment: Thank you yes changing it to  Dictionary<string, string>  worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class model should be like this.

```
public class Incident
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string impact_override { get; set; }
    public bool deliver_notifications { get; set; }
    public string body { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> components { get; set; }
    public IList<string> component_ids { get; set; }
}

public class incidentModel
{
    public Incident incident { get; set; }
}
```

As mjwills said you just need replace this

```
public Components components
```

by this

```
public Dictionary<string, string> components
```

As for services like [json2csharp.com](https://json2csharp.com) and [quicktype.io/csharp](https://quicktype.io/csharp) unfortunately they don't provide the required result.
[image: json2csharp.com]

You can get similar results if you just use standard Visual Studio functionality (just copy a json and use "Paste JSON As Classes" option):
[image: VS Paste as Json]